# Android SQLite comparison

Tags: android, sqlite, null, compare

I want a conditional statement that determines if the table exists. Unfortunately the Cursor data type returns an uncaught exception (and crashes the app) before I can do a null comparison or check for false etc

What is the best way to determine from Java if values in my sql table exist

Comment: Do you want to check for a *table* being there, or for a *value*? It's not clear from your phrasing.

Comment: Value, I know the table exists now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What is the best way to determine from Java if values in my sql table exist?"

```
         SELECT exists
         (select * from T where mycolumn = {some value}  )
```

will return 1 if true or 0 if false, in SQLite.

Comment: the main function that I have to execute SQL queries in android sdk is `sqlitedatabase.execSQL("query string")` this is a void function and has no means to return data from SQL strings

Comment: @RD -- "T" is the convention for "your table". You asked two questions, (1) how to tell if the table exists and (2) how to tell if a value exists in that table. I was showing you the basic structure of query that answers question #2.  You would need to execute that query using whatever database middleware you have at your disposal. You would probably use the .query method from the sdk. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: You should also take a look at the compileStatement method.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this query:

SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';

This queries the sqlite master table and you should be able to see the table you want there.

Comment: I need to see if the table has any values on a particular row. If it does: don't insert, else: do insert . How do I check for values without throwing an exception